# How to replace default SortArgumentResolver

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I need to add `private static final Sort sortById = new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, ID);` to each `Pageable`. I guess, the best way to do that is to create decorator/adapter for `SortArgumentResolver`.

I've created class:

```
public class IdSortArgumentResolver implements SortArgumentResolver {

private static final String ID = "id";
private static final Sort sortById = new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, ID);
private final SortArgumentResolver delegate;

public IdSortArgumentResolverAdapter(SortArgumentResolver delegate) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
}

@Override
public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter methodParameter) {
    return delegate.supportsParameter(methodParameter);
}

@Override
public Sort resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, NativeWebRequest webRequest, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) {
    Sort sort = delegate.resolveArgument(parameter, mavContainer, webRequest, binderFactory);
    if (isNull(sort)) {
        return sortById;
    }
    if (containsSortById(sort)) {
        return sort;
    }
    return sort.and(sortById);
}

private static boolean containsSortById(Sort currentSort) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(currentSort.spliterator(), false)
                        .anyMatch(order -> ID.equalsIgnoreCase(order.getProperty()));
}
```

}

How can I change default `SortArgumentResolver` to `IdSortArgumentResolver` ? Is it possible? or maybe there is a better way to do that...

P.S It's `spring-boot 1.5.2 RELEASE` and current `SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver` is configured in `SpringDataWebConfiguration`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: in your post, your class name is `IdSortArgumentResolver` but your constructor is `IdSortArgumentResolverAdapter`.

Create a configuration class extending `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    // ...
}
```

Override the `addArgumentResolvers` method and configure your `Sort` and `Pageable` resolvers:

```
@Override
public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
    // FIXME Replace null with what you want
    SortArgumentResolver sortResolver = new IdSortArgumentResolver(null);

    // For sorting resolution alone
    argumentResolver.add(sortResolver);

    PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver pageableResolver = new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver(sortResolver);

    // For sorting resolution encapsulated inside a pageable
    argumentResolver.add(pageableResolver);
}
```

**Better solution** without a custom class:

```
@Override
public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
    SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver sortResolver = new SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver();

    sortResolver.setFallbackSort(new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "id"));

    // For sorting resolution alone
    argumentResolver.add(sortResolver);

    PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver pageableResolver = new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver(sortResolver);

    // For sorting resolution encapsulated inside a pageable
    argumentResolver.add(pageableResolver);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting in `spring-data-commons` version `2.0`, there is are 2 new classes that will make this kind of thing easier:

- `SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolverCustomizer`
- `PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolverCustomizer`

Unfortunately that's not the version that ships with the current version of Spring Boot, so replace at your own risk.

```
@Bean SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolverCustomizer sortCustomizer() {
    // s is SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver
    return s -> s.setPropertyDelimiter("<-->");
}
```

In this case, one would probably call `resolveArgument` to manipulate it.

[Spring Data Web Support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web)

Answer (score 1):

for spring boot 2.2.1.RELEASE:

```
@Configuration
public class LocaleConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> resolvers) {
        SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver sortArgumentResolver = new SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver();
        Sort defaultSort = Sort.by(new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.DESC, "id"));
        sortArgumentResolver.setFallbackSort(defaultSort);

        PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver resolver = new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver(sortArgumentResolver);
        resolver.setOneIndexedParameters(true);
        resolver.setMaxPageSize(20);
        resolvers.add(resolver);
    }
}
```