# Spring data - sort by composite primary key with different naming

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have an entity with composite primary key defined as

```
@Embeddable
public class EntityPk {

    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
    Long theNum;

    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
    Type theType;
}
```

and the Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entityXyz")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@DynamicUpdate
@DynamicInsert
public class Entity {

    @EmbeddedId
    EntityPk pk;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    String something;
....
}
```

We have an front-end app that sends the following request

```
{
    ...
    "sort": {
        "field": "theNum",
    }
    ...
}
```

which subsequently after calling pageable with sort parameter:

```
repository.findAll(spec, pageable)
```

fails with

> org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No
> property theNum found for type Entity!

Which could be easily solved by sending the correct request such as:

```
{
    ...
    "sort": {
        "field": "pk.theNum", // notice the added prefix "pk."
    }
    ...
}
```

Finally my question is - is there a way to tell spring to treat the received "theNum" sort argument correctly as part of the composite primary key?

Or I should just either a) change the request from front-end or b) write custom converter for the entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a simple converter that checks the name of the field that the query should be sorted by and prepends

> pk.

to it's name. One thing though - to be sure you are comparing correct field names one should use static metamodel generator such as

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/topical/html_single/metamodelgen/MetamodelGenerator.html

although this is much more elegant solution [Not exposing the path of entities that have a composite primary key to the front end when using the Springframework Page object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57771587/not-exposing-the-path-of-entities-that-have-a-composite-primary-key-to-the-front?rq=1)